# OpenCMIS can't connect to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, opencmis, cmis-workbench

We are unable to configure OpenCMIS with Sharepoint 2010 at a customer site. The client receives a *"401 Unauthorized Access*" message from the server. We have tried using our custom "CMIS Tester" and the CMIS Workbench (versions 0.5 and 0.10) but the result is the same. The only way we have reproduced the issue in our internal environment is by entering the wrong credentials.

We have tried different configurations :

- Atompub (http://[sharepoint server]/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/[repository ID]?getrepositoryinfo)
- Web Service (http://[sharepoint server]/_vti_bin/CMISSoapwsdl.aspx)
- Compression on/off
- Client Compression on/off
- Standard authentication
- NTLM authentication
- Multiple "standard" users
- Sharepoint administrator

We don't have administrative privileges on the customer's Sharepoint environment but the customer showed us that the OpenCMIS plugin (spcmis.wsp) and the CMIS Producer are activated. We also confirm that the user we tried to connect to Sharepoint with had access to at least one library and the "http://[sharepoint server]/_vti_bin/CMISSoapwsdl.aspx" web page.

I'm looking for any tip that could help to identify why we are receiving the 401 error from the Sharepoint server if the credentials we are providing are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped for me, to have CMIS rest working, was enabling BasicAuthentication in IIS on SharePoint web application. I didn't have change anything in the SharePoint configuration itself.

I didn't manage to call CMIS service on SharePoint with Kerberos authentication.

Comment: As we don't have access to the Sharepoint server, we have asked the customer yesterday to enable the basic authentication (It was disabled) at least while we are testing the connector. I will post our findings once we have tested.